# Extends class Application in Android?

Tags: java, android

Should I apply permission at runtime inside class Application? 
Ex: Inside class extends Application I wrote some code instead of I wrote on another class:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PhotoActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PhotoActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PhotoActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PhotoActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    Constants.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_STORAGE);
        }
    }
```

P/s: Sorry for my English :(

Answer (score 0):

if you are targeting devices having MarshMallow OS? Then you have to implement Requesting Permissions at Run Time concept in your code.

**But why it’s necessary to implement?**

Because MarshMallow doesn’t ask for permission, when we install our application.
[image]

It introduces a new feature, i.e. Requesting Permissions at Run Time. It means you have to grant permission for external storage reading/writing, Sending/ Receiving SMS, accessing camera etc at runtime.

This concept is beneficial because users can stay informed about each & every permission which he/ she grants to the application. User can revoke the granted permission through Settings >> Apps >> Take Photo App >> Permissions from his/her device.

If you don’t implement runtime permission, then your application will crash or will not work properly on the device having MarshMallow.

There are 2 types of Permission Categories:

- Dangerous
- Normal

You can learn more about permissions over [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html)

Both types of permissions are necessary to be defined in AndroidManifest.xml but only dangerous permissions require a runtime request.

Normal permissions have been requested at install time and cannot be revoked later. e.g.: android.permission.INTERNET

Answer (score 0):

You can check the permission in `Application` class itself as per **@Abhishek Singh** the permission is needed for target devices of Marshmallow and you have to handle the permission too. for more check [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).